why java not keeping the size of blank space as a character in pdf file
I was trying to create a pdf file java using
new_canvas.drawText("To",20,90,pdf_paint);
in between I wanted to align a few lines one below the other like a table.
for that I added few blank spaces before each Number which i received as input to align each number as amount in a table.
But java doesn't keep the blank space the same size as a character which distorts the alignment.
Is there any way to align each amount to the right of the column by adding spacing infront of each amount
Thanks

I don't understand your question. Where does this method drawText come from? Is this an Android application? If so, you should add the relevant tag, because there are thousands of experienced Java programmers looking at your question who have never touched Android APIs.

yes. android app.

Maybe this is me, but what library are you using for generating the PDF? You're creating a canvas, is the alignment distorted in the canvas or in the resulting PDF?

PdfDocument mypdf=new PdfDocument();
Paint pdf_paint=new Paint();
int page_number=1;
int line_no=0;
PdfDocument.PageInfo new_pdf_pageinfo = new
PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(595,842,page_number).create();
PdfDocument.Page new_pdf_page=mypdf.startPage(new_pdf_pageinfo);
Canvas new_canvas=new_pdf_page.getCanvas(); I am using this code.  But by setting font family to monospace by using pdf_paint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("monospace",Typeface.NORMAL)); this code did the job for me.

This is just a simple proof-of-concept program:

(1) Generate PDF
(2) Align whitespace in the original data
(3) Use monospaced fonts.

The following is a simple Java application Maven project structure. You can verify it on your machine. After confirming that it is feasible, convert it to the Gradle project structure and apply it to your Android project.
Download the specified font.
(You can choose your own monospaced font.)

(1) https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Sans+Mono
(2) Click Button Get font , download Noto_Sans_Mono.zip
(3) unzip Noto_Sans_Mono.zip
(4) open folder Noto_Sans_Mono/static, Please choose the font file you think is suitable. Here I chose NotoSansMono_Condensed-Light.ttf.

Prepare Test Data
This is the test content I have used before. (Print invoice for thermal printer, string formatting issue in javaFX application)
In your program, you can logically generate aligned Text content similar to the following according to your needs.
             Company Name            
-------------------------------------------
Item                        Qty       Price
----                      -----  ----------
Android                       1       12500
Mac OS                        1       12500
Windows 10 Operating System
                              1       12500
Linux Operating System        1       12500
Windows Server OS             1       12500
___________________________________________
Net Amount                             5000
___________________________________________
Thank you so much!


Project Tree
PDFBox_Invoice
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── GenerateInvoice.java
        └── resources
            └── NotoSansMono_Condensed-Light.ttf

pom.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>pdfbox-invoice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>pdfbox-invoice</name>
    <description>pdfbox-invoice Project</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
            <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.24</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>

GenerateInvoice.java
You can generate typesetting Text settings into textData.
package com.example;

import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPage;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDPageContentStream;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.font.PDType0Font;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class GenerateInvoice {
    static String textData =
                    "             Company Name            \n" +
                    "-------------------------------------------\n" +
                    "Item                        Qty       Price\n" +
                    "----                      -----  ----------\n" +
                    "Android                       1       12500\n" +
                    "Mac OS                        1       12500\n" +
                    "Windows 10 Operating System\n" +
                    "                              1       12500\n" +
                    "Linux Operating System        1       12500\n" +
                    "Windows Server OS             1       12500\n" +
                    "___________________________________________\n" +
                    "Net Amount                             5000\n" +
                    "___________________________________________\n" +
                    "Thank you so much!";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(">>>> Text Report START >>>>");
        System.out.println(textData);
        System.out.println(">>>> Text Report END >>>>");
        try (PDDocument document = new PDDocument()) {
            PDPage page = new PDPage();
            document.addPage(page);

            InputStream fontStream = GenerateInvoice.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("NotoSansMono_Condensed-Light.ttf");
            if (fontStream == null) {
                throw new IOException("Font file not found");
            }
            PDType0Font font = PDType0Font.load(document, fontStream);

            try (PDPageContentStream contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page)) {
                contentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(50, 750);
                String[] lines = textData.split("\n");
                for (String s : lines) {
                    contentStream.showText(s);
                    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(0, -15);
                }
                contentStream.endText();
            }

            document.save("Invoice001.pdf");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


NotoSansMono_Condensed-Light.ttf
copy NotoSansMono_Condensed-Light.ttf to PDFBox_Invoice/src/main/resources
Compile and package
mvn clean package

Download dependencies jar
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies -DoutputDirectory=target/libs

Run App
java -cp "target/libs/*:target/pdfbox-invoice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar" com.example.GenerateInvoice

Generated PDF
in project root , Invoice001.pdf

